# SwiftUI multiple windows closing will cause crash

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am creating a second window in my SwiftUI app for Mac.

This is how I call my second window.

```
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 480, height: 300), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.center()
window.setFrameAutosaveName("Add Person")
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: AddPerson())
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

This works fine. However, when I try to close that window, the app is crashing.

I am calling this, to close the window.

```
NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
```

I think there is a problem with opening two windows. Is my opening call correct?

**Edit:** I need to set the `window.number` when I am creating that window. How can I set that? I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think it is because of window itself (I tested your case on Xcode 11.3 with just simple text & button content and it works), but due to some content and/or active objects (managers, etc.)

Anyway, you can try instead of force close (as in provided snapshot) to close via action

```
            NSApp.keyWindow?.performClose(nil)
```

it does the same as clicking close button on window's titlebar.

**Update:** store below window as member, not a local variable

```
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 480, height: 300), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

like main window

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow! // << default, main window
    var window2: NSWindow! // << other window (as example)

    ... // somewhere below

    window2 = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 480, height: 300), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with that code but it still crashes. I get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10193ec0)

Comment: @davidev, does it crash if you click window's close button?

Comment: Yes.. both. If I click a button with your action or the red close icon. The error points me to AppDelegate

Comment: @davidev, I've just noted that you create window on stack - I assume it is the reason. You have to keep reference to it in some member. Updated in answer as well.

Comment: @davidev, no difference in window itself, I just shown that you store it local `let window` but you have to create a member for it somewhere, eg. in AppDelegate, as `window2` and keep it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208270/discussion-between-davidev-and-asperi).